# Is there a way to automate the export of data from a Power BI visual to create monthly snapshot?

Tags: automation, powerbi, report, export-to-csv

I have a report with a couple of visuals and i need to extract the data from one of them (the visual is a table).

- i need to create a monthly snapshot of the data
- the visual is composed by fields from several queries
- i need to extract the data every 1st of the month
- i need to have it extracted to excel(csv) for archiving purposes

Tried power automate, can only download the paginated report (not in excel(csv) format)
Tried Python, having issues with authentication

I've searched around and couldn't find any way of doing this so, i'm open and thankfull for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage PowerBI API to export data on a scheduled basis

Datasets - Execute Queries >> API
MSFT doc link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries

My blogs :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2023/03/02/overcoming-data-size-row-limitations-of-power-bi-rest-api-for-automated-data-extraction-from-dataset/

https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/12/03/extract-data-from-power-bi-through-azure-data-factory-synapse-pipeline-via-t-sql-from-azure-sql-database/

You can get the power query associated with the visual and use it to extract the data from the dataset

Answer (score 0):

I found another way using DAX studio to build my query and run a power automate flow  [Power Automate Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdnWw.png)

Set my schedule, run a query against a dataflow, create a CSV table from the output and create a new file with the CSV table.